# How can I use the Flex Tool easily on LDD?

Tags: ldd

On LEGO Digital Designer, I find it very hard to move the piece being flexed to the correct position.

Are there any tips or musts that I should try to help me flex it into clips etc.?

Answer (score 1):

This eurobricks [thread](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/83515-ldd-tricks/) has several LDD tricks, some of which use the flex tool.

Please be aware however that LDD can easily crash from using the flex tool or the hinge/hinge align tool.

There are other tools to flex parts but they are not as simple to use as LDD's flex tool.